# setTimeout, clearTimeout forming a reset timeout not working. console.log time issue?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout, hyperapp

I currently have a Modal popping up and want it to disappear if the user doesn't input their password for 30 seconds.
This works, but when I tried to implement it with an `onChange` event on the *input* then it stopped working. The weird part is, when I use `console.log` to test it, it works. Once I remove those `console.log`'s, it doesn't work. Just curious if anyone has seen this before?

```
let TIMEOUT = null;

const setModalTimeout = randomFunction => {
  if (TIMEOUT === null) {
    // console.log('NOTE: set timeout before', TIMEOUT, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    TIMEOUT = setTimeout(() => randomFunction(false), MODAL_TIMEOUT);
  }
  // console.log('NOTE: set timeout after', TIMEOUT, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
};

const clearModalTimeout = (done) => {
  if (TIMEOUT !== null) {
    // console.log('NOTE: clear timeout before', TIMEOUT, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    clearTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    TIMEOUT = null;
  }
  // console.log('NOTE: clear timeout after', TIMEOUT, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  done && done();
};

const resetModalTimeout = (randomFunction) => {
  // console.log('NOTE: reset timeout', TIMEOUT, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
  clearModalTimeout();
  setModalTimeout(randomFunction);
}
```

Above is the logic, below is the input tag.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="pin/password" id="password" oncreate={element => element.focus()} onchange={() => resetModalTimeout(randomFunction)} />
```

The main part of this issue is, if I uncomment the `console.log`s, it works perfectly. The way the code is shown now, it does not work. It will only go through the *First* cycle (so only work for 30 seconds even though I make a change to the input). and when I log, it clearly shows that change goes through. Any ideas? Of course, I don't want the `console.log` in the main code, also I am using *hyperapp* (existing code base).
When Logging, I can see the `TIMEOUT` value changing as expected.

Comment: Where is `TIMEOUT` originally defined? `let TIMEOUT = null`

Comment: @epascarello Sorry i should've mentioned that as well! I have it outside of the scope, when logging i can see the value changing (to null and to an integer, etc)

Comment: Can you please provide a verifiable code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what the issue was. With more debugging, my coworker and I realized it was related with the lifecycle hook. It should be `oninput` rather than `onchange`. On my computer, `onchange` was working just fine when logging (not too sure why if someone has an answer to that), but not on my coworker's computer. When changed to `oninput` it worked just fine for us both. `onchange` was waiting for the focus to leave the *input*.